# running CPU intensive tasks in react native

Tags: javascript, android, performance, react-native

I am running a CPU intensive task to generate a cryptographic proof,This works quickly in dev mode but takes 2-3 minutes to compute in release mode.
As I understand, the dev mode uses chrome's v8 engine while release mode uses javascript core of react native.
is there anyway to boost performance?

Comment: in general, using Javascript for CPU-intensive tasks is inefficient. Concider implementing those algorithms using Java, or even using NDK

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko: I considered this , but the problem is there is no matching java library for generating a similar proof and we cannot migrate this code to java due to the complex maths involved.

Comment: `no matching java library` is OK, as not everything was already implemented in libraries. `we cannot migrate this code to java due to the complex maths involved` I don't believe there is something in JS impossible with Java. But that's not me who decides how you do your work. I understand that there are tasks that are not worth to do.